# Parent Child Concept in SQL Server Relational Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have a `Teacher` and a `Student` table in SQL Server. I want to use the inheritance concept to make a table with the name `Person` and put the common attributes of `Student` and `Teacher` there.

Practically how can I do it?

What I want to know is:

- how a `Person` record will show in `Student` table?
- If I update the name from `Student` how will it get updated in `Person` table and etc.

Please help me I don't know anything about to try and I need it badly please...

Comment: Create teacher and student as dimension and Person as a fact table..and relate them as Primarykey-ForeignKey relationship..

Comment: @anwaar_hell please tell me in details or recommend me any tutorial sir as i told u i am completely new in this so please..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms179610.aspx,http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/TENc260912-Difference-between-Primary-Key-and-Foreign-Key.html

Comment: If you don't need to edit the person table, the easiest solution is to create a view.

Answer (score 1):

"Teacher" and "student" would be your tables that inherit from "Person".

`person` stores all the details that are common for both teachers and students (eg, name, address, contact info etc)

`teacher` stores specific info for teachers, and a foreign key pointing to the `person` table to identify their personal information. similarly, `student` stores information specific to students

your person table could look like

```
+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
| person_id |  fname  |  lname   |    dob     |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
|         1 | tracey  | wright   | 10/10/1990 |
|         2 | max     | smith    | 11/11/1998 |
|         3 | chris   | brown    | 12/06/1978 |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
```

lets assume that tracey and max are students, and max is a teacher.

Your `teacher` table could look like

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| teacher_id | person_id | speciality |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|          1 |         3 | maths      |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

`teacher_id` is the table identifier, and `person_id` is the the one that chris has in the person table. This now identifies chris as a teacher

Similarly, your student table could look like

```
+------------+-----------+------------+--+
| student_id | person_id | detentions |  |
+------------+-----------+------------+--+
|          1 |         1 |          4 |  |
|          2 |         2 |          5 |  |
+------------+-----------+------------+--+
```

This now identifies tracey and max as students (and for example, specific information regarding the students might be number of detentions)

In each case, with `teacher` and `student`, `person_id` is used as a foreign key. Foreign keys are primary keys within another table, thus allows other tables to reference each other.

In order to access the information for each record, you would need to use a `join` statement. Depending in the DBMS you are using, this varies in syntax (see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp to get a proper understanding)

Comment: this was really help full for me @Takarii  if i am registring a student i have forum with First Name, last Name, and Study etc.
mean to say forum contain some attributes of Person table and some specific attributes of Student table how i can submit the data on one signup button?

Comment: to clarify, your data looks something like -> first name, last name, address, course?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can learn about creating relationship between tables..
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-primary-and-foreign-keys-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/